# Accessing rails_admin url helpers from Rspec files

Tags: capybara, rspec2, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-admin

I am using Rails 3.2, RailsAdmin 0.0.3, Rspec and Capybara.

I try to call RailsAdmin url helpers from my spec file as it is explained in the RailsAdmin wiki. `rails_admin.new_path(:model_name => :user)`

When I use the helper that way from a controller or a view it works nice but when trying to use it from a spec file it gives this error:

> undefined local variable or method `rails_admin' for #RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2:0xbe04948>

I guess that I have to add something to my spec_helper.rb file in order to load rails_admin. But after googling for a while and looking to rails_admin gem's spec_helper, I cannot figure out what...

Any help will be apreciated!

Answer (score 7):

I found it in [spec_helper.rb](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/spec/spec_helper.rb) of rails_admin.

Include the following code into spec_helper.rb.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  ...
  config.include RailsAdmin::Engine.routes.url_helpers
end
```

I tested using debugger. It can be called

```
> new_path(:model_name => :user)
=> "/admin/user/new"
```

Comment: Seems like `config.include RailsAdmin::Engine.routes.url_helpers` crashes my non-admin page tests. Is there a way to plug in RailsAdmin url helpers on per test class basis?

Answer (score 0):

I added this line to individual specs that needed rails_admin urls and it allowed me to reference the methods mentioned in a prior post, but without interfering with my non-admin urls.

```
include RailsAdmin::Engine.routes.url_helpers
```

Example of method within spec

```
index_path(:model_name => :client)
```

I am using Rails 5.0, Rspec 3.5 and Capybara 2.10.1